# Can't boot a live usb on windows 7

Tags: usb, windows-7, 14.04

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (I have tried 64 and 32bits) but I always get this, It doesn't matter if 1 hour has passed

[image]

BTW, a CD with Ubuntu 12.04 does work.

Comment: Thaks for the answers guys, I have a laptop with a intel 64 bits.  

I've downloaded and booted around 10 times the 64 bits version that is here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop  
But it's not working

Comment: @Jay Aurabind I can't open a terminal because I haven't installed ubuntu yet

Answer (score 0):

Format your USB stick, and make bootable usb again using UNetbootin: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Try download ISO again (64 - make sure your machine support it)

Answer (score 0):

1. If your computer is 64 bits, always go for the `amd64` (aka `x86_64`) iso version. Because 32 bits programs are back compatible with 64 bits, and you get to make use of the full hardware support.
2. Next, verify if you downloaded the correct medium. Compute the checksum: Open a terminal and type `md5sum ~/Downloads/<file_name>.iso` and check if it matches the values mentioned in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes
3. I would recommend using `pendrivelinux` as mentioned in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows, because Unetbootin might break EFI partition setup on your flash drive.
4. Reboot to BIOS to change boot order if you haven't done that yet and reboot again.